# WooCommerce get order shipping address as separate fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a WooCommerce plugin which sends orders to a 3rd party api.

However, I have found there isn't a way to get the individual fields/properties of the order shipping address since WooCommerce v2.3. The only function available is

> get_formatted_shipping_address()

Which returns a string and it seems the function which returns an address array "get_shipping_address()" has been Deprecated in version 2.3.

Does anyone know a way to get the shipping address as an array for an order? I don't really want to resort to using an old version of WooCommerce. Perhaps there is a hook, action or class override I can use to achieve this?

Comment: did either my or Josh's answer help? If so, can you accept one? If not, did you come up with your own solution? If you did that's great, you should write it up here for others to find. Best, Tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the shipping address in this simple way :

```
function get_shipping_zone(){     

global $woocommerce;
$post_code = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_postcode();
$zone_postcode = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_postcode();
$zone_city =get_shipping_city(); 
$zone_state = get_shipping_state(); 

}
```

You can also print_r for the "$woocommerce->customer" you will get the all meta data you may need, it is very useful to know it.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the 'get_order' function of class 'WC_Api_Orders'

```
        'shipping_address' => array(
            'first_name' => $order->shipping_first_name,
            'last_name'  => $order->shipping_last_name,
            'company'    => $order->shipping_company,
            'address_1'  => $order->shipping_address_1,
            'address_2'  => $order->shipping_address_2,
            'city'       => $order->shipping_city,
            'state'      => $order->shipping_state,
            'postcode'   => $order->shipping_postcode,
            'country'    => $order->shipping_country,
        ),
```

You can just directly access the properties of the order.

Answer (score 2):

I'd look at WC_Abstract_Order for both of these public functions.

```
    /**
     * Get a formatted shipping address for the order.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_formatted_shipping_address() {
        if ( ! $this->formatted_shipping_address ) {

            if ( $this->shipping_address_1 || $this->shipping_address_2 ) {

                // Formatted Addresses
                $address = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_shipping_address', array(
                    'first_name'    => $this->shipping_first_name,
                    'last_name'     => $this->shipping_last_name,
                    'company'       => $this->shipping_company,
                    'address_1'     => $this->shipping_address_1,
                    'address_2'     => $this->shipping_address_2,
                    'city'          => $this->shipping_city,
                    'state'         => $this->shipping_state,
                    'postcode'      => $this->shipping_postcode,
                    'country'       => $this->shipping_country
                ), $this );

                $this->formatted_shipping_address = WC()->countries->get_formatted_address( $address );
            }
        }

        return $this->formatted_shipping_address;
    }
```

And ...

```
    /**
     * Calculate shipping total.
     *
     * @since 2.2
     * @return float
     */
    public function calculate_shipping() {

        $shipping_total = 0;

        foreach ( $this->get_shipping_methods() as $shipping ) {
            $shipping_total += $shipping['cost'];
        }

        $this->set_total( $shipping_total, 'shipping' );

        return $this->get_total_shipping();
    }
```

Hope this helps,

Tim